# How do I solve this system of four equations? Can it be done using Gaussian elimination?

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I have the following system of four equations:

$$\begin{align} &x_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} x_2 + \dfrac{1}{4} x_3 \\ &x_2 = \dfrac{1}{3} x_1 + \dfrac{1}{2} x_4 \\ &x_3 = \dfrac{2}{3} x_1 + \dfrac{1}{2} x_4 \\ &x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1 \end{align}$$

How do I solve this system to get a unique solution for $\mathbf{x}$? I tried doing it by hand by substituting the first equation into the second, and then the third into the second, and then everything into the last one, but that doesn't work. I could use an online calculator, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how it is done by hand. Is there a more systematic/orderly way to do this, such as with Gaussian elimination / row reduction?

Comment: Put all the unknowns on one side, then represent this system as a matrix, and the system has a unique solution iff it is row equivalent to identity matrix. Do gaussian elimination (elementary row operations) on the matrix to see whether that is the case. When you get used to these exercise, you may determine that it is/isn't row equivalent to identity matrix way before you get to the identity matrix

Comment: You should use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @korone what does “put all the unknowns on one side” look like for the first three equations? I’d like to see a step-by-step demonstration of how it’s done.

Comment: for example for equation 1, you have $x_1-\frac12x_2+\frac14x_3 = 0$, and for 2nd eq then $x_2 -\frac13x_1-\frac12x_4 = 0$. You see how it is done? Now there is a well-known theorem that says once you write everything in this form you can represent the system as $AX = Y$, which has a unique solution for any $Y$ iff $A$ is row equivalent to $I$

Comment: @korone oh, ok, yes, I see what you’re saying. And then how is the Gaussian elimination set up? I know how to do the elementary row operations, but what about the remaining constants on the right-hand side (the $0$s and $1$)?

Comment: Row reduce the augmented matrix $[A|Y]$ so that $A$ becomes the identity $I$ and you get $[I|Z]$. A theorem says that if $[A|Y]$ is row equivalent to $[I|Z]$, then $AX = Y$ has the same solution as $[I|Z]$

Comment: @korone $A$ is our coefficients of the $x$, right? What is $Y$?

Comment: yep! and $Y$ is the constant $4x1$ matrix that remains on the right hand side. So here it is $(0,0,0,1)^T$

Comment: @korone but shouldn’t $Y$ be a matrix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121226/discussion-between-korone-and-the-pointer).

Comment: @korone ok, so $Y$ doesn’t actually need to be the same dimensions as $A$. So after we convert $A$ to the identity matrix, is $Y$ our solution for the $x$ values?

Comment: Well when you convert $A$ to identity, as long as you make sure you are converting $Y$ along with $A$, then what $Y$ is converted to will be the solution once $A$ becomes $I$

Comment: @korone ok, thanks. I will try this and see what happens. I’ll leave this question open for anyone that wants to post a worked solution, so that I can verify mine.

Comment: Give me, please, your solution in order I check mine.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I got $(9/50, 11/50, 7/25, 8/25)$

Comment: So, I am correct ! Your solution is the correct one. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you want to use substitution.*

Solve the first equation for $x_3$; plug it. Solve the second equation for $x_4$; plug it. Solve the thirs equation for $x_2$.

At this point, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as expressed as functions of $x_1$. Plug in the last equation and solve for $x_1$ and go backward to get the other.

Comment: “plug it” where? Which equations are you referring to at each of these steps?

Comment: @ThePointer. "Push" everything in the lhs so $0$ is your rhs. The equations are the ones you wrote.

Comment: yes, but when, for instance, we solve for $x_3$, do we plug it into the third or fourth equation? That’s what I mean.

Comment: @ThePointer. Yes, for sure. This is successive elimination.